# Can't deserialize list with anchor YamlDotNet

Tags: c#, serialization, yamldotnet

I think this [might be a problem with YamlDotNet](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/issues/819) but that does seem somewhat unlikely given that it's quite a well used library so figured I'd ask.

I have this bit of yaml:

```yaml
Methods:
  - Name: "AddPgfPlotWithAxes"
    Arguments:
      - Name: "axisType"
        Type: "AxisType"
      - Name: "options"
        Type: "AxisOptions?"
    CanTransitionTo: &AxisSettingsCircular
      - "AddPlot"
      - "SetXLabel"
      - "SetYLabel"
      - "SetXMin"
      - "SetYMin"
      - "SetXMax"
      - "SetYMax"
      - "SetMinorXTickNumber"
      - "SetMinorYTickNumber"
      - "SetXTicks"
      - "SetYTicks"
      - "SetGrid"
  - Name: "SetXLabel"
    Arguments:
      - Name: "label"
        Type: "string?"
    CanTransitionTo:
      <<: *AxisSettingsCircular
```

I want to deserialize it onto this class:

```cs
internal record FluidApiMethodDefinition
{
    public required string Name { get; init; }
    public string? ReturnType { get; init; }
    public List<string> CanTransitionTo { get; init; } = new();
    public List<FluidApiArgumentDefinition> Arguments { get; init; } = new();
}
```

I think I should be able to with this snippet of code:

```cs
IDeserializer deserializer  = new DeserializerBuilder().WithNamingConvention(NullNamingConvention.Instance).Build();
FluidApiMethodDefinition methodDefinition = deserializer.Deserialize<FluidApiMethodDefinition[]>(_rawYml);
```

However, I get this error:

> (Line: 44, Col: 7, Idx: 980) - (Line: 44, Col: 7, Idx: 980): Expected 'SequenceStart', got 'MappingStart' (at Line: 44, Col: 7, Idx: 980).

Line 44 in this case corresponds to the line with `<<:` on it, I've just not included the full yaml, or the nesting (`Methods`) exists inside another class) for brevity.

I've [verified that the yaml is valid and parses as I'd expect](https://codebeautify.org/yaml-parser-online/y238010bb) but maybe I'm doing something else wrong here that's YamlDotNet specific?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax I was trying to use is actually not supported according to the [YAML spec](https://yaml.org/type/merge.html). You can merge mappings, not sequences.

However, what I was wanting to achieve can be achieved with:

```yaml
Methods:
  - Name: "AddPgfPlotWithAxes"
    Arguments:
      - Name: "axisType"
        Type: "AxisType"
      - Name: "options"
        Type: "AxisOptions?"
    CanTransitionTo: &AxisSettingsCircular
      - "AddPlot"
      - "SetXLabel"
      - "SetYLabel"
      - "SetXMin"
      - "SetYMin"
      - "SetXMax"
      - "SetYMax"
      - "SetMinorXTickNumber"
      - "SetMinorYTickNumber"
      - "SetXTicks"
      - "SetYTicks"
      - "SetGrid"
  - Name: "SetXLabel"
    Arguments:
      - Name: "label"
        Type: "string?"
    CanTransitionTo: *AxisSettingsCircular
```